# My significant other has stuff from a past relationship that is also part of his work

Tags: relationships

My significant other got rid of old stuff and things he not longer needs from his house, that included things from past relationships.

But I saw the other day in his desk some songs he wrote to his ex, I didn't say anything since he is a musician and his job is to make music. However, it feels as if he kept them to entertain nostalgic sentiments for his ex.

I am concerned and wonder why he has kept stuff from other relationships? I always get rid of past relationship things, but I can't expect for everyone to do as me. I don't want to cause trouble, but i do feel uncomfortable, since he keeps contact with her due to parenting. I don't want to be the person that demands him to get rid of things that he worked on. I'm sure if I bring this up he will throw them away or at least change their name.

My question is, how do I talk to him about this? What do I say in a way that he does not become defensive or offended?
I will talk to him but before that I want to think this through.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I am missing the actual question. Can you clarify?

Comment: If the question is "Should I allow him to do this?" that's opinion based.  If you'd like to find help approaching talking to him about why he kept it and expressing your discomfort, you'll need to rephrase your question to say so... As it stands it's hard to figure out exactly what interpersonal skill we could help you with.

Comment: well,is it ok to keep things from other relationships? I don't know how to approach him on this. after all it is not only part of his past love life but also his creative work.

Comment: "I don't want to be the person that demands him to get rit of things that he worked on" - you obviously *do* want to be that person, though.

Comment: His relationships in the past made him to be the man he is. So why would he throw it away? Is he still singing those songs for her? If yes, just ask him why on a casual basis.

Comment: would you be happy if the songs were away from his desk, in a box on top of his wardrobe for example?

Comment: Yes, I usually have trouble, because I don't know wheter is a matter of self thought or something that needs an action from him. @sgroves, I would feel better if he didnt kept that, as i do with my past relationships. but again I don't want to demand anything, as i would expect him not to demand me to throw away things i appreciate

Comment: Maybe it helps you to research on how many great songs we would be missing, if all songs related to former spouses would be destroyed in any case.

Comment: If I wrote songs for someone, I might keep them beyond the point where that person is no longer part of my life because I am proud of my work and/or I value the memories. (I do in fact still have certain items from my first girlfriend despite being unlikely to ever see her again and lacking any romantic interest in her for these reasons. I would fully understand my girlfriend asking about it - I would be upset if she tried to make me throw them away)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to resolve your feelings on this issue.  So you should talk to him about it.

**1)  ask him for a half hour to talk about something very important**.   you could say something like:

> Honey can I have a half hour (or 15 mintues ) about something that has
>   been bothering me?

**2) tell him how you feel.**  Stay calm and don't accuse him of anything, and keep it short for now.  You'r just giving him the background on why you wanted to talk.

**3) Ask him why he keeps the songs.**  Make sure to listen to what he says.   You could swap the order of #2 and #3  based on what you think will help him feel less "accused" of wrong doing.

**4) continue discussing things as needed.**

**5) Decide if you are ok with him keeping the songs or if you are not.**

Once you've  made your decision you may need to have another conversation with him.

Good luck figuring out how to feel about those songs.

---

Edit #1 It's not really related to the question but I felt the need to add some advice on staying calm during hard conversations.

Every time feelings escalate (voices rise in volume or pitch,  or your heart starts beating fast) try doing the following.

1)Pause, just stop talking a take a few second pause.  You can pause for 10 seconds or more if needed.
2) take a deep slow breath. Repeat until your feeling calmer.

Comment: thanks, I will reflect on it. I think what worries me is making it appear as if he had done something wrong. however i do feel uncomfortable. i will do as you said.

Comment: @AndreaMora  You know you should express that exact sentiment when you start the conversation.  "I'm worried because I don't want to imply that you are doing anything wrong, however I just feel  uncomfortable."